# How to control two picker view contents simultaneously yet separately?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[image: two picker view with same data content]

i want to control two picker view simultaneously and convert it from one to another. its for my area converter app in swift.

here's my code ,

```
@IBOutlet weak var Picker1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var dataEntered: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

var inputArray = ["Hector","Bigha","Kattha","Ropani","Daam"]
var outputArray = ["just", "checking","to ", "add","another"]
var wheelContent = []

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return wheelContent.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return inputArray.count    
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return inputArray[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    _ = inputArray[row]

}

@IBAction func convertButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    resultLabel.text = "hello"


}
```

Comment: how to get value of selected component of the scrolling compartments ?                   if user selects "Ropani" in the left side and "Bigha" on the right, and inputs "25" and click "convert", I need to fetch the selected component from both compartments and provide logic to convert from one to another units and change the label. i need to repeat it for each possible combinations of available pickerContents. logic : Ropani = 1/20 Bigha

Answer (score 0):

In you case you can just use two compartments for the picker view you don't need two picker views.

```
var dataSource:[String] = ["Hector","Bigha","Kattha","Ropani","Daam"]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       return dataSource.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
      return dataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let from = dataSource[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    let to = dataSource[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]

    if value = Int(string:textField.text){
        let result = Converter.convert(from: from, to: to, value: value)
    }
}


class Converter: NSObject {
    static func convert(from from: from, to: to, value: value) -> Float{
        // do the conversion logic
    }
}
```

If you really want two picker views you can implement the `dataSource` and `delegate` in it's own class. That way you can instantiate two of those classes in your `UIViewController`

Comment: how to get value of selected component of the scrolling compartments ?                   if user selects "Ropani" in the left side and "Bigha" on the right, and inputs "25" and click "convert", I need to fetch the selected component from both compartments and provide logic to convert from one to another units and change the label. i need to repeat it for each possible combinations of available pickerContents. logic : Ropani = 1/20 Bigha

Comment: You'll have to write that conversion logic for yourself but the picker view code is updated for your specific problem

Answer (score 0):

You should make a translation class that calls a method whenever something is selected in your first picker view. You'll want to tighten it up using an `NS_ENUM` or two to bond your answers to your query, but this is one way to do it, if you are just taking an `NSString` as an input (a `switch` statement is recommended if your library is static and enumerated clearly):

```
func conversionForString(stringToConvert: String) -> String? {
    if (stringToConvert == "Kattha") {
        return "Ropani"
    else if (stringToConvert == "Ropani") {
        return "Daam"
    } else {
        return "Kattha"
    }
}
```

After this, once you have your converted string, you need to look for it in your second `UIPickerView`, and get the row that it's located at. Then, call this method:

```
let selectedRow = 3 // assuming you found it at row 3
secondPickerView.selectRow(row: selectedRow, inComponent: selectedComponent, animated: true)
```